# IF statement in OpenQASM on IBM Quantum Experience

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, textbook-and-exercises

This is a simple circuit introduced in Moran's book "Mastering Quantum Computing with IBM QX" to demonstrate how *if* works in OpenQASM:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[5]; // Quantum Register
creg c[5]; // Classical Register
 
x q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
if (c==1) x q[1];
measure q[1] -> c[1];
```

And this is how the circuit visually looks in IBM QX Circuit Composer:

[image]

The book states that at the end of the circuit, the classical register should read *00011* because after the first measurement it holds a value 1 (as a decimal number), thus satisfying the *if* condition. However, when I test this exact circuit in IBM QX's Circuit Composer, the result shows *00001* with 100% probability.

Interestingly enough, when `if (c==1)` is changed to `if (c==0)`, the result is now *00011* with 100% probability, which I don't think is logically right.

What should be an explanation for this discrepancy? The book argues that the *if* statement is not supported by IBM QX (as of Jan 2019), so could this be a sort of bug?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I think is, indeed, a bug in IQX.</del> There is an explanation for this, but it is a bit obscure. It will be explained later.

Your code is correct:

Here is the result in Qiskit.

With `c==1`:

```
from qiskit import *
qc = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str("""
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[5]; // Quantum Register
creg c[5]; // Classical Register
 
x q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
if (c==1) x q[1];
measure q[1] -> c[1];
""")
qc.draw('mpl')

backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
execute(qc,backend).result().get_counts()
```

```
{'00011': 1024}
```

With `c==0`:

```
from qiskit import *
qc = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str("""
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[5]; // Quantum Register
creg c[5]; // Classical Register
 
x q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
if (c==0) x q[1];
measure q[1] -> c[1];
""")
qc.draw('mpl')

backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
execute(qc,backend).result().get_counts()
```

```
{'00001': 1024}
```

### Why this does not work on IQX visualizations

There is note in [the IQX documentation for visualizations](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/iqx/visualizations):
[image]

The key part is:

> The visualizations do not reflect any measurement operations in your circuit.

That means that your `measure` statement is ignored, leaving your code like this:

```
x q[0];
if (c==1) x q[1];
```

The initial state of `c` is 0. Therefore, just `x q[0];` resulting in `00001`.

When you changed to `c==0`, then the circuit is `x q[0]; x q[1];`, resulting in `00011`.

I talked with the IQX developers and they are working in a better solution to avoid skipping measurements silently. You can still run your program in IQX using a simulator backend and the result will be the correct one. This issue only pops up in the client-side visualizations, since they are statevector based.